# how to fix the exception getting while export to excel

Tags: c#, exception, visual-studio-2008, export-to-excel

I have equity record and when I try to export it from the website which must be converted to excel and download, instead I am getting an exception called "RadGrid must be databound before exporting.". Please tell the reason for the exception. I am coding in visual studio 2008 using c#.

Comment: You should add RadGrid to Page's controls collection before exporting it. Note that this won't affect your page but only the exported file.

Comment: Please post the code where you get this exception

Comment: sorry . . cant show the code... its critical